# W3 validator -> using <script type="text/javascript"> within body of html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I trying to validate my page but have one error to fix.

I am using Google charts within my code. to populate the chart i require data to be filled in within the JavaScript shown in the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



      function drawChart() {




        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  <?php echo $data; ?>   ]);



        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ <?php echo $datagoing; ?>   ]);


        var options = {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            legend: 'none',
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px',
               chartArea: { height :"95%", width:"95%" },

        };

        var options2 = {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            legend: 'none',
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px',
               chartArea: { height :"95%", width:"95%" },
        };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart<?php echo $loop ?>'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechartgoing<?php echo $loop ?>'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);

      }
    </script>
```

this is within a loop so the code is generated multiple times as you can see by looking at the source of my page http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php?venue=Warwick&time=3:05

my question would be how can i do this while keeping the page html validated: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmr-tipster.com%2Fpages%2Fnewcard.php%3Fvenue%3DWarwick%26time%3D2%3A30&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Aside from the script issue, you can reduce your code dramatically by including your `drawChart` function just once, then calling it with the required parameters.

Comment: Did you gave all this code in `PHP WHILE`?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the use of `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` intended? If you're not particularly aware of the differences between XHTML, HTML 4.01, and HTML5, you could try changing your top line to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` (HTML5) and see how well that validates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are placing the script between `tr`s directly inside the `<table>` tag and [that is not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table-content-model). What you have now:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
    ...
</table>
```

To solve it quickly, move the script inside the last `<td>` of the row (`<script>` is a [flow element allowed in the table cell](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html#td-content-model)). The effect will be the same, and it will validate without problems. Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        ...
        <td>
            ...
            <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

---

But if you want to solve the issues in a cleaner and more elegant way, you should do as Rory suggests in the comments: create a function, and simply call it changing the parameters, instead of having huge blocks of almost identical code.